# Why does emacs (getenv "TERM") return incorrect data?

Tags: term, environment

I'm running *Emacs 25.2.2* on *Ubuntu 17.10*.  Although my environment has `TERM=xterm-256color`, `(getenv "TERM")` returns `dumb`, which is incorrect.

Why does `(getenv "TERM")` return an incorrect value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting `startup.el`:

```
;; Subprocesses of Emacs do not have direct access to the terminal, so
;; unless told otherwise they should only assume a dumb terminal.
;; We are careful to do it late (after term-setup-hook), although the
;; new multi-tty code does not use $TERM any more there anyway.
(setenv "TERM" "dumb")
```

If Emacs didn't set `TERM=dumb` then every subprocess invocation would need to do so manually.

Comment: End-User Documentation (i.e., https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html#Top) in section C.4 reads, "The environment is a feature of the operating system... Inside Emacs, the command M-x getenv reads the name of an environment variable, and prints its value in the echo area."  The documentation specifically refers to $TERM.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use `(getenv-internal "TERM" initial-environment)` to get the original value of $TERM.

Comment: But this interferes with 24-bit true color that needs a specific terminfo.